# Previous activity get destroyed on view-pager page change

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-ondestroy

My Previous Activity gets Destroyed on view-pager page changed(of running Activity). Thus onBackPressed() my App gets closed. I don't want to recall previous Activity explicitly.

Assume FirstActivity then open SecondActivity which has one viewpager . When we change page in view pager in Second Activity then FirstActivity (which is in Background) gets destroyed. so when we come back and back press on SecondActivity application closed

Comment: `"recall explicitly"`? what you mean?

Comment: show the related code

Comment: @pskink I want my application go on previous Activity onBackPressed. don't want to call previous Activity with new Object

Comment: and it will go if you press back button (or call `finish()` method)

Comment: add this method on onCreate() or Toolbar setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

Comment: *@pskink no actually not...........let me explain.....I am on **FirstActivity** then open **SecondActivity** which have one **viewpager** . When we change page in view pager **FirstActivity** get destroyed. so when we come back and back press on **SecondActivity** application closed

Comment: no, even if `FirstActivity` gets destroyed it will be created again by a system and its `onCreate` method will be called again, for more see [Understand Tasks and Back Stack](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack)

Comment: In the Android debug menu under "Apps" there's an option "Don't keep activities" which will do this. Can you check that that's off? However technically I think it is documented that Android is allowed to do this, destroy activities as soon as you move on, but no version of Android so far (IIRC) actually does.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether you have called `finish();` after starting the `ViewPager` activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SomeActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish(); // This will destroy current activity.
```

Comment: no i don't as I wanted to come to the same Activity after some operation performed

Comment: check the activity is present or not by calling isFinishing(). This will return false when your activity is no longer present.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use finish() method for your activity while starting a new Activity explicitly. Instead, you should handle your activity every time in onBackPressed() method. if you manage your activities using lifecycle states i think you will not need for further explicit call to your activity.